# Opening a modal window in qt 4.8.6

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a simple program for installing wow addons and need some help with having the main window open a preferences window. I'm rather new to Qt and struggling a bit with the documentation. I did some looking around on stackoverflow, but still am a bit stuck on getting things in the right area.

edit: added in error message.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**preferences.h**

```
#ifndef PREFERENCES_H
#define PREFERENCES_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Preferences;
}

class Preferences : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit Preferences(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~Preferences();

private:
   Ui::Preferences *ui;
};

#endif // PREFERENCES_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "preferences.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();

   return a.exec();
}


void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()
{
   Preferences = new PreferencesDialog(this);
   Preferences->show();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "preferences.h"
#include <QtGui/QDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**preferences.cpp**

```
#include "preferences.h"
#include "ui_preferences.h"

Preferences::Preferences(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Preferences)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

Preferences::~Preferences()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**Error Received**
    error: no'void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()' 
    member function declared in class 'MainWindow'

I put the mainwindow.ui file on pastebin as it was to jumbled up here because of the tooltips added.

http://pastebin.com/ZXrDxZXz

Comment: What's the error? You didn't mention it.

Comment: Basically I'm having trouble getting it to show the preference window if you did read everything.

    main.cpp:15:

    error: no 'void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()' member        function declared in class 'MainWindow'
 void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you want your dialog to be modal, use QDialog::exec(). If you want a modeless dialog, use QDialog::show(). You can use show() to display a modal dialog too by setting the modal property to true.

I've fixed up your code so that it compiles and runs. First, the compiler error you're getting is exactly what it says: you've implemented a function MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered() that you haven't declared in your class definition. But there are some other issues. I'll start with the main.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "preferences.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.resize(200,200);
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}


/* Move this to mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()
{
  Preferences = new PreferencesDialog(this);
  Preferences->show();
}*/
```

I commented out the on_Preferences_triggered function, because it should be moved to the mainwindow.cpp file, where the rest of the MainWindow class is implemented. I also resized the MainWindow instance you created in the main() function.

On to mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "preferences.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private:
  /* add a function to set up a menubar/menu (you could do this in the constructor instead) */

  void setupMenus();


  /* Your main window doesn't need an instance of Ui::MainWindow, it IS an instance*/
  //Ui::MainWindow *ui;

  /* It needs a Preferences instance, though */
  Preferences *pref;


private slots:
  void on_Preferences_triggered();


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

First, in both your Preferences and MainWindow definitions, you have instances of Preferences and MainWindow, respectively. I'm not sure why you did that, but I don't think it's what you want. MainWindow needs a Preferences instance (which I added), but I don't think either class needs an instance of itself.

Next, I added your on_Preferences_triggered() function as a slot. You'll need this. Finally, I added a setupMenus() function, which sets up the menubar, though you could do this in your constructor if you wanted to.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
//#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

/* Move this to mainwindow.h */
//#include "preferences.h"
#include <QtGui/QDialog>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
//ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  //ui->setupUi(this);

  /* initialize your preferences window */
  pref = new Preferences(this);

  /* add a menubar with a menu that will allow you to open the preferences windwow */
  setupMenus();

  /* You need a central widget: */
  setCentralWidget(new QLabel("Central widget", this));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  //delete ui;

  /* You can explicitly delete the Preferences pointer, but Qt will take care of it, since its parent is this  */
}

void MainWindow::setupMenus()
{
  QMenu *menu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Menu"));
  QAction *prefAction = new QAction("Show preferences", this);

  /* Crucial: connect the action's triggered signal to your on_Preferences_triggered slot */
  connect(prefAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_Preferences_triggered()));

  menu->addAction(prefAction);
}

void MainWindow::on_Preferences_triggered()
{
  /*Preferences = new PreferencesDialog(this);
  Preferences->show();*/
  pref->show();
  pref->setModal(true);
}
```

According to the documentation, a QMainWindow without a central widget isn't supported... so I added a QLabel as a placeholder. The rest of the constructor is pretty self-explanatory... allocate your Preferences pointer, call setupMenus.

The setupMenus function does the important work. The menubar is created the first time you call menuBar(), so I called it and added a menu. Then I created a QAction which will be used to show your preferences dialog. To do this, you NEED to connect the action's triggered() signal to your on_Preferences_triggered() slot.

The on_Preferences_triggered() slot is pretty much what you had, except it doesn't create a Preferences instance (it could though... you could keep what you had). An important point here: I used pref->show() to pop up the dialog, then made it modal with pref->setModal(true). You could instead have used pref->exec(). But read Kuba Ober's comment below.

Then, in preferences.h:

```
#ifndef PREFERENCES_H
#define PREFERENCES_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Preferences;
}

class Preferences : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit Preferences(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~Preferences();

private:
  void setupDialog();

  /* Preferences doesn't need an instance of Preferences */
  //Ui::Preferences *ui;
};

#endif // PREFERENCES_H
```

I added a setupDialog() function, and again, got rid of the instance of Preferences, because I think you don't need it.

And preferences.cpp:

```
#include "preferences.h"
//#include "ui_preferences.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

Preferences::Preferences(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent)
//ui(new Ui::Preferences)
{
  //ui->setupUi(this);
  setupDialog();

}

Preferences::~Preferences()
{
  //delete ui;
}

void Preferences::setupDialog()
{
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

  layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Preferences Dialog"));
}
```

I just created a dummy layout with a dummy QLabel in the setupDialog function.

Also... I commented out your #include "ui_preferences.h" and "ui_mainwindow.h" statements, because you didn't include this code. Not sure what you'd done in those headers, or whether they were important.

Comment: In general, using the `exec()` and `waitForXxx()` methods is a recipe for disaster, since you're making all of your code reentrant. There's absolutely no need to use `exec()` at all. In my copy of Qt, I've made all those blocking methods private - with the sad exception of `QDrag`.

Comment: That's pretty unhelpful. Could you please post a full example, proposed fix or some sort of resource I could use as I stated I'm a newbie to Qt.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't have an error message posted yet, I just thought you didn't know how to make a window modal. I'll post a fix shortly.

Comment: My apologizes if I seemed rude and for leaving out the error code at first. I tend to get frustrated easily when things aren't working. :P One question I have is that I already have a menu implemented with QtCreator using the designer. How would I go about using that? I'll add the ui file to the first post.

Comment: I added a pastebin link cause it was to hard to format with all the tooltip strings I added for the buttons.

http://pastebin.com/ZXrDxZXz

Comment: I haven't used QtCreator, so I'm not sure... it looks like setupUi() will automatically connect your slots to the appropriate signals if you name them appropriately (which you did). Check this part of the Qt docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect But if you call menuBar() (in your MainWindow class) after you've called setupUi(), you'll get the menubar you've set up in the XML file. You just can't retrieve the existing menus, unless you make them member variables.

Comment: Alrighty thanks. I ended up picking up a book on both on Qt development and on qt creator. I'll mark this as solved for now.